# Finding ordinary and singular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just have a quick question regarding the following ODE:

$$P(x) y'' + Q(x) y' + R(x)=0.$$

To find the singular points of this ODE, is it correct to set $P(x)$ to $0$ and just solve for the $x$ terms? Or is there another method for finding the singular points. I understand you can take the limit of both $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ over $P(x)$ respectively to check whether a given point is singular/ordinary.

But my main question is, if I am asked to specifically FIND the point, is setting $P(x)$ equal to $0$ and solving for the x values the correct method?

How about for finding ordinary points? Is there a method to find the point, or do I just look at $P(x)$ and think to myself, what values of $x$ can I plug into $P(x)$ such that $P(x)$ will not equal $0$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will work for some ODEs, but not all. For instance, the ODE

$$xy''+y'+y=0$$

has one singular point at $x=0$, which your method would find. However, the ODE

$$xy''+xy+\tan(x)y=0$$

has a singularities at $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2+\pi n$. Your method would not find the latter. Why?

The formal definition for singularities starts by rewriting your ODE in the form

$$y''+\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}y'+\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}y=0$$

We then ask if the functions $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ and $\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}$ are *analytic*. If you aren't familiar with the term analytic, it essentially means that the functions have an infinite number of well-defined derivatives (you can take derivatives forever). If either of those functions are not analytic at some point $x_0$, we call that point a *singular point*. In the first example, we have

$$\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{1}{x}$$

which is not analytic at $x=0$ since it blows up to $\infty$. In the second example, we have

$$\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}=1$$

and

$$\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{\tan(x)}{x}$$

Note that $\tan(x)$ blows up to $\pm\infty$ at $x=\pi/2+\pi n$. Thus, there are singularities at $x=\pi/2+\pi n$. I suggest you read up on analytic functions if this isn't clear to you. Once you've found all the singular points, all other points are *ordinary points*.

Comment: Oh damn!! "Once you've found all the singular points, all other points are ordinary points." I didn't even realize that before but yes that makes sense now!! Just to clarify what you've said in your answer, your suggestion would be instead of setting P(x) equal to 0, I look at Q(x)/P(x) and R(x)/P(x) and ask myself 'where do these functions blow up to infinity'. And you suggest doing this to avoid missing out singular points caused by certain functions on the numerator such as tan(x)? Is this correct?

Comment: @melm Technically, you should be asking if they are analytic. Typically, just looking for where they blow up to infinity is good enough, yes. If you start getting really weird functions though, you need to be more rigorous with your definition of analytic.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help!

Comment: ${\tan x \over x} \to 1$ near $x=0$, would that still make it a singular point?

Comment: @Dylan correct... It is analytic at x=0, my mistake taking a limit incorrectly.